# Incremental Circuit Of This Amplifier

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, norton

Can anyone explain to me the incremental equivalent circuit of this amplifier?
[image]

the solution is this :
[image]

I have some trouble understanding the resistor RB placement and also the Resistor R1 and R2.

Comment: In the "solution" shown by you - where is the negative feedback effect caused by the RB path ?

Comment: I think this is the Open-Loop small signal circuit equivalent  (with the feedback loading effects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a small signal equivalent circuit, which is used to analyze circuit behavior for a small ac signal. For that reason, all capacitors and DC sources are treated as shorts.

For instance, the VCC and the emitter are shorted to ground. As a result, in the equivalent circuit, R1 and rπ appear in parallel with R2.

The circuit has a negative feedback resistor, RB, connected between the collector (output) and the base (input). This is an ac feedback (due to CI, it does not affect the DC operating point of the transistor) and, therefore it should be included in the ac analysis.

As suggested in the comments, the equivalent circuit does not show the effect of this feedback, i.e., it is representing an open loop, where the gain and other characteristics of the circuit are analyzed with the feedback broken. Based on that analysis, closed loop characteristics could be calculated later.

Still, when open loop is analyzed, the effect of RB has to be taken into account, since it presents additional load both for the input and for the output signals. In the equivalent circuit, RB is connected directly to ground, in both input and output sections, which does not quite match the circuit - it is likely an approximation, since RB is substantially bigger than RI and RC.